# "This folder is shared with other people" when deleting not shared folder

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

After applying some .NET Framework updates (I installed .NET Framework 4.5 and MVC 4 from stand-alone packages), I got `D:\934f8a71184fd47ed258f943` folder. When I attempt to delete it Explorer says:

```
This folder is shared with other people
If you delete this folder, it will no longer be shared.
```

[image]

although the folder is **NOT** shared.

What is going on?

The contents of this folder is:

```
DHtmlHeader.html
DisplayIcon.ico
header.bmp
netfx_core_x64.msi
netfx_core_x86.msi
netfx_extended_x64.msi
netfx_extended_x86.msi
netfx_Full_GDR.mzz
netfx_Full_GDR_x64.msi
netfx_Full_GDR_x86.msi
netfx_Full_LDR.mzz
netfx_Full_LDR_x64.msi
netfx_Full_LDR_x86.msi
netfx_Full_x64.msi
netfx_Full_x86.msi
ParameterInfo.xml
Setup.exe
SetupEngine.dll
SetupUi.dll
SetupUi.xsd
SetupUtility.exe
SplashScreen.bmp
sqmapi.dll
Strings.xml
UiInfo.xml
watermark.bmp
Windows6.0-KB956250-v6001-x64.msu
Windows6.0-KB956250-v6001-x86.msu
Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu
Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x86.msu
Windows8-RT-KB2881468-x64.msu
Windows8-RT-KB2881468-x86.msu
1025\eula.rtf
1025\LocalizedData.xml
1025\SetupResources.dll
1028\eula.rtf
1028\LocalizedData.xml
1028\SetupResources.dll
1029\eula.rtf
1029\LocalizedData.xml
1029\SetupResources.dll
1030\eula.rtf
1030\LocalizedData.xml
1030\SetupResources.dll
1031\eula.rtf
1031\LocalizedData.xml
1031\SetupResources.dll
1032\eula.rtf
1032\LocalizedData.xml
1032\SetupResources.dll
1033\eula.rtf
1033\LocalizedData.xml
1033\SetupResources.dll
1035\eula.rtf
1035\LocalizedData.xml
1035\SetupResources.dll
1036\eula.rtf
1036\LocalizedData.xml
1036\SetupResources.dll
1037\eula.rtf
1037\LocalizedData.xml
1037\SetupResources.dll
1038\eula.rtf
1038\LocalizedData.xml
1038\SetupResources.dll
1040\eula.rtf
1040\LocalizedData.xml
1040\SetupResources.dll
1041\eula.rtf
1041\LocalizedData.xml
1041\SetupResources.dll
1042\eula.rtf
1042\LocalizedData.xml
1042\SetupResources.dll
1043\eula.rtf
1043\LocalizedData.xml
1043\SetupResources.dll
1044\eula.rtf
1044\LocalizedData.xml
1044\SetupResources.dll
1045\eula.rtf
1045\LocalizedData.xml
1045\SetupResources.dll
1046\eula.rtf
1046\LocalizedData.xml
1046\SetupResources.dll
1049\eula.rtf
1049\LocalizedData.xml
1049\SetupResources.dll
1053\eula.rtf
1053\LocalizedData.xml
1053\SetupResources.dll
1055\eula.rtf
1055\LocalizedData.xml
1055\SetupResources.dll
2052\eula.rtf
2052\LocalizedData.xml
2052\SetupResources.dll
2070\eula.rtf
2070\LocalizedData.xml
2070\SetupResources.dll
3082\eula.rtf
3082\LocalizedData.xml
3082\SetupResources.dll
Graphics\Print.ico
Graphics\Rotate1.ico
Graphics\Rotate2.ico
Graphics\Rotate3.ico
Graphics\Rotate4.ico
Graphics\Rotate5.ico
Graphics\Rotate6.ico
Graphics\Rotate7.ico
Graphics\Rotate8.ico
Graphics\Save.ico
Graphics\Setup.ico
Graphics\stop.ico
Graphics\SysReqMet.ico
Graphics\SysReqNotMet.ico
Graphics\warn.ico
```

My system is Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of the way the Access Control List is queried by Windows Explorer to determine if the folder is shared. because this folder you tried to delete is a child folder of a parent folder and the two folders have a different security entries, Windows will treat as a shared folder. This causes Explorer to give you the warning that you received.

Answer (score 2):

Could be wrong, but if it's like the problem I just had after creating folders with Cygwin, permission has been granted to 'Everyone' by whatever process created the folder - so if you go to 'Properties > Security', it'll say 'Everyone' in the 'Group or user names' box along with 'Authenticated Users' and the other stuff you'd expect to be there. If you delete that 'Everyone', you should then be able to delete the folder without the warning.

Answer (score 2):

You receive a Share warning popup when deleting a folder which has modified ACL's

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2493924

Comment: The link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

Simple, that folder is shared, even though you don't think it is. :)

Unless you can prove it isn't shared, that's what I'd stick to.

If it still exists, run a `net share` from an elevated command prompt and see if it's listed as a shared folder; if it is, then it's shared.

BTW the folder is a left over install folder for .Net update - specifically from this MS KB: [An update is available for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958488)